# c++: Schedule function call in the future?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc, timer

Using Visual C++ with MFC.  When a certain event occurs in my code, I want to set a function to be called 10 seconds later to perform some activity.  The handling of the event happens in a static library that doesn't have any direct links to MFC (and I'd like to keep it that way).

How can I schedule a function to be called at some point in the future? Use a Timer I guess?  How do I decouple the Timer (which is an MFC dependency) so my business code doesn't have a direct dependency on the GUI? Or maybe something else besides a timer?

**Update**

Recently started reading about the [Command Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern) which seems promising for my situation.  The description is (my emphasis):

> In object-oriented programming, the command pattern is a design
>   pattern in which an object is used to represent and encapsulate all
>   the information needed to *call a method at a later time.*

Answer (score 3):

**Approach 1**
Write a wrapper function for the call to the static library.
Before the static-library call, do a sleep for the required duration.

**Approach 2**
Use a Win32 timer http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1236/Timers-Tutorial#Win32Timers

You can avoid the MFC dependency in both approaches.

Comment: I think a sleep won't work because my business logic is called from the GUI thread so a sleep in that thread would probably cause the GUI to hang.  The Win32 timer is slightly better than MFC but still dependency on Win32.  I was thinking maybe some TimerService class that abstracts the timer and is dependency injected into my business class..

Comment: Got it. C++11 has conditional variable too.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a secondary thread and tell it wait 10 seconds and than call the function. This way it will have the least impact on rest of the your program in terms of GUI responsiveness and ensure your function will be called irrespectively after 10 seconds.